# Div height dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, css, resize

I have this **HTML** code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="feedbackBox"></div>   
</div>
```

The **#feedbackBox div** doesn't appear in, initially.

The **CSS** is to centralize the div:

```
#container {
    position: absolute; width: 380px; height: 360px; left: 50%; top:50%; padding: 30px;
    margin-left: -220px; margin-top: -210px; 
}
```

But I need to change the `height` of **#feedbackbox** via jQuery.

I tested it and it doesn't work:

```
.expandInfo {
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: -221px;
}

$("#container").removeClass().addClass('expandInfo');
```

But it doesn't work! The CSS class doesn't apply, much less has been re-done (the calculation) so that the div remains centralized.

Comment: You are applying CSS to `#container`, not the div within.

Comment: youre using ccs classes instead off css classes

Comment: set the margin-top: 0 and then see what happens (thinking that the css is being applied but the div is off the screen).

Comment: putvandre, this is right. I need to increase the container size when feedbackbox appear. As my container is fixed size, need to increase the height via code. Piis not found a way to centralize the div without using fixed size.

Comment: No no jeff, the div is centralized in the screen. Is an login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height does not change, because of different selector priorities. (http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Training/Priority_level_of_selector)

You set the height for *#container* **by ID**. The height for *.expandInfo* is defined **by class**. But in CSS the ID-selector has a higher priority than the class-selector.

Try that:

```
#container.expandInfo {
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: -221px;
}
```

This selector has ID priority **and** class priority. It will override the height of `#container`

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example
http://codepen.io/alfonsodev/pen/aKwiG

I've seen you are using #container in the css and then removing class.
as container does not have any class does not make sense.

Look at the example container has a class container, then on click you can show the box and apply the class you want.